# How to map WSGI responses in AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-api-gateway, wsgi

I deployed a Flask application to AWS Lambda using aws-wsgi. I created a couple resources in AWS API Gateway and mapped their methods to my lambda. I can now POST/GET to these resources and I get "a response" (see below). I understand this response is in some WSGI standard but I would like to translate it to "just a response". Right now my endpoints return JSON but I'd like to be flexible an support other content types that my Flask application may return. How do I configure the mapping in the response of the API gateway to reformat the response appropriately? I have the default "Integration Response" (with Output passthrough: Yes) but I don't know what to do in "Method Response".

This is the response I'm getting:

```
{
"isBase64Encoded": false,
"statusCode": "200",
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Content-Length": "47"
},
"body": "{\n  \"key1\": 1, \n  \"key2\": 3, \n  \"key3\": 2\n}\n"
}
```

I'm using Flask and aws-wsgi (https://pypi.org/project/aws-wsgi/) for no particular reason, I saw there are other similar projects (e.g. https://github.com/adamchainz/apig-wsgi) and I'm open to try alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "Integration Request" tick the "Use Lambda Proxy integration".